# Unable to compile class for JSP,Only a type can be imported

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jfreechart

**Hello,friends. I met a problem when I try to visit the jsp page .

my jsp import some jars

```
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset,org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory
,org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart,org.jfree.chart.servlet.*" %>
```

Tomcat debug display :**

> Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Test] threw
>   exception [Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file:
>   [/Users/JinCan/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/work/Catalina/localhost/Test/org/apache/jsp/jfreeChart_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset
>   resolves to a package
>
> An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file:
>   [/Users/JinCan/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/work/Catalina/localhost/Test/org/apache/jsp/jfreeChart_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory resolves to
>   a package
>
> An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file:
>   [/Users/JinCan/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/work/Catalina/localhost/Test/org/apache/jsp/jfreeChart_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart resolves to a
>   package
>
> An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file: /jfreeChart.jsp
>   DefaultPieDataset cannot be resolved to a type

**I have already put the jars in WEB-INF/lib
how do I change ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (more readable) for SO:

```
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart" %>
```

You can only import a type, so this will not work:

```
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.servlet.*" %>
```

And make sure [jfree librar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.13)y is included:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have ran another demo , it's OK , so I sure the reason isn't caused by jars.

Comment: @CanJin have you removed the invalid import?

Comment: Thx, today I recheck my project .I guess the reason is that my tomcat could't  found the jar. When I created my project , I put those jar in the directory of WEB-INF/lib , I don't know why  tomcat made such a mistack. Thx u.